# How to disable auto-scaling on UWP mobile

Tags: c#, mobile, uwp, uwp-xaml

I´m doing a Windows Universal app that will run **only** on Lumia 640XL devices. That device has a native resolution of 1280 x 720 and a pixel density of 259 ppi. 
There will be no desktop version so I just care about the mobile layout.

The design guide lines for my app are huge and full of pixel measures (sizes, margins, paddings, font sizes) everywhere, so what I´d like is to make the mobile app respect the physical pixels (rather than "effective pixels"), as the desktop version does.

How can I disable auto-scaling?

There is a link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/disable-scaling?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) saying how to disable scaling on Xbox:

```
bool result = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewScaling.TrySetDisableLayoutScaling(true);
```

but that `ApplicationViewScaling` does not seam to be available on mobile:

[image]

The UAP version I´m using is 10.0.10586.0

Comment: I tested this code. It has nothing wrong when running on a Lumia640. Why you said it is not available.

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT I attached the error. What UAP version are you using?

Comment: That´s it then. I´m trying to update to 14393 on VS 2015 update 3, but it´s getting hard. Thanks for your input.

Comment: ok, it doesn't support in build 10586 uwp app. According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewscaling) it can support xbox from 10240 but uwp app from 14393. Update your environment is a better solution or you must have a workaround for 10586?

Comment: Yeah, I will just update my env. Thanks again