# How to desible scaling a UWP app programatically

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

How can I prevent that the content of my UWP app after changing the default Windows scaling being scaled? Windows scaling should no longer affect UWP app scaling.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452892/disable-scaling-for-uwp-app) helped me a little but it doesn't work.

My Code:

```
public App()
{
    ApplicationViewScaling.TrySetDisableLayoutScaling(true);
}
```

Comment: Like Barry said, this API only works for XBox device. If your UWP app runs on desktop, it will not work. Please submit a **Feature Request** on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is apply a scale transform to your pages to maintain the layout without having things shift around. I assume that's what your want.

I suggest you layout your elements using x y coordinates in a canvas and then apply the scale transform when your page changes size.

Hope that helps. I've used this method to design layouts to fit many screen dimensions without having to spend a lot of time on adjusting layouts to be reactive.